# Return an array and its length via function argument by double pointer and reference repectively C++

Tags: c++

I was solving a C++ assignment about creating `array3` to save the sum of `array1` and `array2`, and the format basically looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  double* array3= new double[n3]; 

  // addition() taken and returns array3 with length n3;
}
```

So far I'm sure the results are good, yet the topic requires me to return `array3` and its length `n3` via function argument, saying the third and the fourth ones, by double pointer and reference repectively.

I'm not familiar with function arguments before, yet by grabing some other cases, I wondered if it expects I add something like

```
argv[3]=**array3; // double pointer
argv[4]=&n3; //reference
```

I tried, but it is not successful in compile.

Thanks for assistance in solving this :]

Comment: It appears the instructor want you to write another function, in addition to `main` that looks something like `void addition(double array1[], double array2[], double * array3[], int & n3)`. You can eliminate passing in `array1` and `array2` if they are somehow already inside `addition` or otherwise accessible from inside `addition`. `argv` in `main` is a list of pointers to null terminated character arrays containing the command line the program was invoked with all nicely split up for you. Trying to put a `double` array or an `int` in it is not recommended.

Comment: I see, so indeed the instructor wants me to pass the third and fourth argument in the addition function instead of ones in main(). I misunderstood the meaning.

Comment: When you pass a pointer as a parameter, the function receives a *Copy Of* the pointer which holds the same memory address as the original. That's fine, unless you have to reallocate storage to grow the size of the array. (the address for the reallocated block would be assigned to the copy and lost on return leaking memory). So you pass the *Address Of* the pointer, so the function receives a copy of your pointer holding the address of the *Original Pointer*. Now you can reallocate and assign to the original *Pointer* address so the change is available back in the caller (`main()` here).

Comment: Tip: In C++ you should steer towards using `std::vector` or `std::array` and stay away from `new[]` if you can help it. Consider arguments like `const std::vector<double>&` when passing these around.

Comment: The need for `n3` by reference is strange. Since `addition` doesn't require any change in size, so you need `n1` and `n2` also in order to probably allow the sum of arrays of different sizes.